# Remove .wine folder in home directory

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, nfs, wine

I am a NFS with a very restrictive limit on how much space we can take up on the hard-drive. I found out my `.wine/` in my home folder is pretty big. I want to know if I can go ahead and remove it, as I never use wine, and the only time I have ever used it was by complete accident.

I don't want to just start deleting files though, so I was wondering if it mattered if I deleted it. I can not uninstall wine, as I do not have root privileges on the machine. I am hopeful user specific preferences are stored in this folder, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That folder should just contain Wine specific profile files and files installed in the virtual Windows-like environment via Wine. Its basic structure is easily recreated by just running `wine` again.

You could/should check *why* it takes up a lot of space, though, so you don't accidentally delete some useful data that you have forgotten about. I just did a test, and a clean Wine profile directory takes up 16 MB on my system — if yours is a lot larger, you probably have something hidden there.